# Sending Integer Count in Push Notification Using Java

Tags: java, web-services, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am Using GCM for Sending Push Notification in Android. But is there any way to send one integer with that means that is count i need to show in the app. Notification count.  so how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was too easy. all i have to that add next data into the GCM message. here the ans is.

```
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Message message = new com.google.android.gcm.server.Message.Builder()
.collapseKey("GCM_Message").timeToLive(30).delayWhileIdle(true).addData("message", From_Email).addData("count", badge_no+"").build();
```